# MySQL "In" clause using PHP / CLI

Tags: php, mysql, command-line-interface

I'm trying to update table records using PHP exec with following command  :

```
exec("mysql --user=USER --password=PASS DB_NAME > 
      UPDATE `table` SET option_value='VALUE' where option_name in ('val1','val2')")
```

It gives me following error : `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. How can I use In clause in PHP / CLI?

Note : I know i can use OR operator instead and Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

Comment: Why on earth dont you just connect to the database and use `mysqli` or `PDO` to do the update

Comment: using php tag, but not using mysqli_*

Comment: @RiggsFolly I can't otherwise I wasn't here asking a question. This should be automated by PHP.

Comment: Creating a connection and performing a query in php script __is__ an automation. Executing a query to datatbase can be performed even as a `bash` script, why use `php` then?

Comment: What is **not automated** about running a simple query from the PHP CLI code. You can connect to a database in just the same way in PHP CLI as you do in PHP on a web page. And its a F* sit easier ___and more predictable___  than issuing `exec` commands

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm setting up another project using my existing project based on input given by user. So database, user and password creation is perform by php script. Also I've one pre defined db structure that should be imported using php as well

Comment: No sure what information you intended to impart to me there, but nothing in what you say could not be done by PHP CLI script(s) using a connection to a database which would allow you to so all that directly from PHP code

Comment: That would also allow for much better error situation processing, giving you so much more control over whatever happened

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm also wondering what will happen when the shell expansion sees the back-ticks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use ">" to execute SQL statement, ">" is used to write the output into a file, and "<" is used to read statements from a file.

In your case, "-e" is sufficient to execute the SQL, as below:

```
exec("mysql --user=USER --password=PASS DB_NAME -e
      UPDATE `table` SET option_value='VALUE' where option_name in ('val1','val2')")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the '(', the error is thrown by bash not by php. Also you can change the " to ' and escape the '. Also apply the -e as Vivek said.

```
exec("mysql --user=USER --password=PASS DB_NAME -e 
      UPDATE `table` SET option_value='VALUE' where option_name in \('val1','val2'\)")

exec('mysql --user=USER --password=PASS DB_NAME -e 
      UPDATE `table` SET option_value='\''VALUE'\'' where option_name in ('\''val1'\'','\''val2'\'')')
```

Answer (score 1):

The character ">" means that you are redirecting the standard output instead of executing the query. Use the option "-e QUERY" instead. Read the documentation of bash (`man bash`) and mysql_cli (`man mysql`) before continue.